# Java RandomAccessFile A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released

Tags: java, android

OK this is a weird one.

I have an Android app which keeps a buffer of everything the user has typed on their keyboards in a file (buffered.log). Everything works perfectly, except in the weird situation where the clients install the app on somebodies phone that they have previously installed it on.

The app then throws this error:

```
03 20:20:34.678 22741-22749/com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                             java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:127)
at com.radicalninja.logger.FlushableCipherOutputStream.<init>(FlushableCipherOutputStream.java:50)
at com.radicalninja.logger.CipherUtils.flushableEncryptedBufferedWriter(CipherUtils.java:31)
at com.radicalninja.logger.FileWriter.openFileWriter(FileWriter.java:41)
at com.radicalninja.logger.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:30)
at com.radicalninja.logger.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:0)
at com.radicalninja.logger.LogManager.openExternalPublicStorage(LogManager.java:161)
at com.radicalninja.logger.LogManager.createFileWriter(LogManager.java:115)
at com.radicalninja.logger.LogFileController.openLogFile(LogFileController.java:18)
at com.radicalninja.logger.LogFileController.<init>(LogFileController.java:12)
at com.radicalninja.logger.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:0)
at com.radicalninja.logger.WordBuffer.<init>(WordBuffer.java:0)
at com.anysoftkeyboard.AnySoftKeyboard.onCreate(AnySoftKeyboard.java:328)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3808)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:222)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

My question is: how can i check if a random access file was not closed properly, and close it before the app tries to create the same new `RandomAccessFile` the previous install was already using?

Comment: The more pertinent question is why didn't you release the resource?

Comment: Hi EJP, the reason the resource isn't released is because the buffer is permanently keep open whilst app is running to capture keyboard input, every two hours, it is closed, the buffer of words is uploaded to AWS, then the buffer file is open again.

Comment: It all works fine for the client, EXCEPT when the client accidently installs the app again on somebodies phone that already had it installed. It's not a common problem (once in hundreds of installs), but just trying to track down all possible issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this is my cludge fix for this issue:

Create new file with the same path when app first opens, and then delete it.

Seems to work, but doesn't seem very elegant